# USBtinyisp not showing up in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino

So, I have tried everything I know how to do to solve this.  Granted, that's not a lot.  When I use either the Arduino IDE, or Eclipse with the Sloeber add in, I am unable to select a Port to program my device.  The Ports menu item is greyed out as though there are no ports to select from.  I am fairly sure it is not a permissions issue as I have addressed that.

Here is what I have:

1. Lenovo Laptop
2. UBUNTU 18.04.04 (just reinstalled to see if that was a problem)
3. Arduino 1.8.12 (latest)
4. Eclipse (latest)
5. USBTinyisp programmer
6. Arduino nano

I also have a desktop machine that works perfectly and is similarly configured.  I know the hardware works on the desktop.  On the laptop I can program the device using the USB port directly, but not using the programmer.  With a direct USB connect the port menu item allows me to select /dev/ttyUSB0.

What I have done:

1. I added myself to the dialout group.
2. I added a .rules file for the programmer.  It has this data

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1781", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0c9f",        MODE="666", GROUP="dialout"`

3. I can see the programmer with the lsusb command.

   `Bus 002 Device 011: ID 1781:0c9f Multiple Vendors USBtiny`
4. udevadm monitor gives the following results:

   ```
           KERNEL[62983.772850] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0        /usb2/2-2 (usb)
           KERNEL[62983.773098] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
           KERNEL[62983.773185] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
           UDEV  [62983.784387] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
           UDEV  [62983.789501] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
           UDEV  [62983.791610] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
   ```

   All the same as my desktop, which works fine, so I think I am doing the

right thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and yes, I have to use the USBtinyisp because on my production board the serial port is in use therefore I can only program the device using the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

First, in the terminal window, go to `/snap/arduino/current` and execute `./arduino-linux-setup.sh username`, where username is your login username.

```
cd /snap/arduino/current

./arduino-linux-setup.sh username
```

Restart your system

Connect USBtinyISP and open Arduino IDE.

Use **ctrl+shift+U** (capital or active caps) to upload your sketch, or go to Sketch menu and click 'upload using programmer'

USBtinyISP doesn't open a serial port!

This works for me.

Hope this helps.

regards,